# NullPointerException when loading JSON data with RetroFit using two queries

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm developing an app that pulls data in JSON format from an API when a user searches a name, and can pick between searching for an artist or album. I'm using RetroFit to call the JSON data and want to use two queries in my interface.

Code to call JSON data:

```
public void ArtistSearch() {
    String searchTerm = searchTxt.getText().toString().trim();
    String searchCat = searchPick.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(api_url).addConverterFactory
            (GsonConverterFactory.create());
    final Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
    ArtistClient client = retrofit.create(ArtistClient.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = client.getArtistList(searchTerm, searchCat);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {
            List<ArtistList> artists = response.body().getArtists();
            Log.d(TAG, "Artists found");
            Log.d(TAG, "Number of artists:" + artists.size());
            artistAdapter = new ArtistAdapter(DiscogSearchPage.this, artists);
            discogList.setAdapter(artistAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Fail: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface ArtistClient {

    @GET("/database/search")
    Call<JSONResponse> getArtistList (@Query("q") String searchTerm, @Query("type") String searchCategory);
}
```

Currently when I try to run this I get the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List ...Responses.JSONResponse.getArtists()' on a null object reference.

However if I comment out the second query in the interface and remove `searchCat` from the code the data loads fine. I have no idea what is going on.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:** For those asking for model classes and JSON response.

JSON response class:

```
public class JSONResponse {

    @SerializedName("results")
    @Expose
    private List<ArtistList> artists = null;
    // Getters and setters
```

ArtistList class:

```
public class ArtistList {

    @SerializedName("thumb")
    @Expose
    private String thumb;
    @SerializedName("title")
    @Expose
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("uri")
    @Expose
    private String uri;
    @SerializedName("cover_image")
    @Expose
    private String coverImage;
    @SerializedName("resource_url")
    @Expose
    private String resourceUrl;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;
    // Getters and setters
```

JSON response, with search "Drake" and type "artist":

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "per_page": 50,
    "items": 22893,
    "page": 1,
    "urls": {
      "last": "https://api.discogs.com/database/search?%3Ftype=artist&q=drake&secret=AEmHdfwlGwPqUYQpTBVrarEtzjKsykih&key=wMWTrOWaTkfHDUQVXFSG&per_page=50&page=458",
      "next": "https://api.discogs.com/database/search?%3Ftype=artist&q=drake&secret=AEmHdfwlGwPqUYQpTBVrarEtzjKsykih&key=wMWTrOWaTkfHDUQVXFSG&per_page=50&page=2"
    },
    "pages": 458
  },
  "results": [
    {
      "thumb": "https://img.discogs.com/Voe5_n4NEBvrIW2AczQyGb389WM=/150x150/smart/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(40)/discogs-images/A-151199-1520497976-7068.jpeg.jpg",
      "title": "Drake",
      "uri": "/artist/151199-Drake",
      "cover_image": "https://img.discogs.com/nFMZ1bVcXA3bLHxR_0LVSrRB7iM=/456x615/smart/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/A-151199-1520497976-7068.jpeg.jpg",
      "resource_url": "https://api.discogs.com/artists/151199",
      "type": "artist",
      "id": 151199
    },
    // results objects continue
```

Comment: `getArtists()` may be returning as null when passing `searchCat`,have you checked the response with postman or any such tools

Comment: @Navneetヅ Yeah I have, works fine using Postman.

Comment: share **postman response**  with the question

Comment: @Navneetヅ It displays a huge JSON response of some 500+ objects, I can't copy all that in here, unless there's something else you want?

Comment: is your get url like this `baseurl/database/search?q=something&type=something`

Comment: @Navneetヅ Yeah that's correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169096/discussion-between-navneet--and-yellowman94).

Comment: Actually the exception says that your invoking `getArtists()` on `null`. So it's not the return value of `getArtistss()`, but what you're calling it on that is `null`. I think in this case it's this line `response.body().getArtists()`, which means the response body is null. This can be for several reasons. Can you post the received json and your model classes pls?

Comment: Hi @Fred please see my edit

Comment: OK, looks good from the code perspective. Are you sure this is the json you get in the app? Is it possible that you're getting a different one where done fields are missing?